# How to restore files of failed Kazam video

Tags: video, kazam

Basically, after being OCD by pressing the power button while recording, a prompt to shut down popped up. I exited out of it, and pressed again, nothing happened, but I clicked on the power button that appears on the upper right menu (Gnome 3.16) and it shutted off immediately after, borking my recording. in the next boot, left over files were left, and I deleted all but one .movie file, because I thought it worked. One day when I decided to watch it though, the video would cut out in the middle of the super long video, and now I'm panicking here.

Is there anyway to get the .movie file (and maybe other files) to properly work perfectly and/or convert it to .mp4? Or something? Help? Or is the video borked?

Comment: Any Luck? I 'm not seeing much in the way of answers.

Answer (score 0):

Your file is kind of broken. I have same problems with many broken videos I recorded using *Kazam* :(
I used this http://grauonline.de/cms2/?page_id=5software to **PARTIALY** recover my video and:

- I had no audio
- **Only 50% was recovered** as this program in free version recovers only 1/2 of your movie.
- I needed to run it in **Windows** (did not try wine maybe works.)

Maybe full version allows to fix all video maybe even with sound? If anyone will decide to buy it please write in comments your experiences.